# how to get the renamed file name after uploaded into input text area in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, image-uploading

This is my PHP function to upload image file into directory
In this function, all image files will be renamed after upload automatically, so, I'm gonna get renamed file name after upload and insert it into input text area.

**functions.php**

```
    function createDir($path){      
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    $old_mask = umask(0);
    mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE);
    umask($old_mask);
}
}

function createThumb($path1, $path2, $file_type, $new_w, $new_h, $squareSize = ''){
/* read the source image */
$source_image = FALSE;

if (preg_match("/jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG/", $file_type)) {
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
}
elseif (preg_match("/png|PNG/", $file_type)) {

    if (!$source_image = @imagecreatefrompng($path1)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }
}
elseif (preg_match("/gif|GIF/", $file_type)) {
    $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($path1);
}       
if ($source_image == FALSE) {
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
}

$orig_w = imageSX($source_image);
$orig_h = imageSY($source_image);

if ($orig_w < $new_w && $orig_h < $new_h) {
    $desired_width = $orig_w;
    $desired_height = $orig_h;
} else {
    $scale = min($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);
    $desired_width = ceil($scale * $orig_w);
    $desired_height = ceil($scale * $orig_h);
}

if ($squareSize != '') {
    $desired_width = $desired_height = $squareSize;
}

/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
// for PNG background white----------->
$kek = imagecolorallocate($virtual_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($virtual_image, 0, 0, $kek);

if ($squareSize == '') {
    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
} else {
    $wm = $orig_w / $squareSize;
    $hm = $orig_h / $squareSize;
    $h_height = $squareSize / 2;
    $w_height = $squareSize / 2;

    if ($orig_w > $orig_h) {
        $adjusted_width = $orig_w / $hm;
        $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
        $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, -$int_width, 0, 0, 0, $adjusted_width, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
    }

    elseif (($orig_w <= $orig_h)) {
        $adjusted_height = $orig_h / $wm;
        $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0,0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $adjusted_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
    } else {
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
    }
}

if (@imagejpeg($virtual_image, $path2, 90)) {
    imagedestroy($virtual_image);
    imagedestroy($source_image);
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

**This is upload image form:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image_upload_demo_submit.php" method="post" name="image_upload_form" id="image_upload_form">
<div id="imgArea"><img src="./img/default.jpg">
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="imgChange"><span>Change Photo</span>
    <input accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file" type="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's my input text area form in registration page**

```
<form method="post" name="gregorian" onclick="calcPersian();" action="../medical/patient_new.php">
<input rows="3" cols="30" id="avatar" name="avatar" value="" type="text">
</form>
```

> How to insert renamed file after upload into input text area
>   **avatar**?

Thanks in advance